# send mail using mail() in php

Tags: php, email

Hello I am learning php where i came to know mail() function i have tried this code

```
function sendMail()
{
    $to = 'Sohil Desai<sohildesaixxxx@gmail.com>';
    $from = 'Sohil Desai<sohildesaixxxx@hotmail.com>';
    $subject = 'Test Mail';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

    $message = 'This mail is sent for testing.';

    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if (!$mail) {
        return 'Error occured sending mail.';
    }

    return 'Mail successfully sent.';
}

echo sendmail();
```

I have tested only for gmail, ymail and hotmail.

This function sends mail in a spam for gmail & hotmail and it won't send mail to ymail.

why it happens??

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 & php version 5.3.10.

Can anyone help me?? Thanks to halpers in advance..

Comment: Did you check the mail server to see if the mail is sending or not?

Comment: @sal00m: Yes that's why it sending mail in spam for gmail & hotmail

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "to" as a header:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
```

More details can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (example #4).

Comment: What are you basing on? Could you add an explanation to this?

Comment: thank you but nope still same result i am not getting mail on yahoo to be specific on this email sohildesai.2711@yahoo.in and for gmail & hotmail still getting mail in spam/junk

Comment: @jackflash Basing it on [the PHP manual for sending HTML mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3357) and also on lots of trial and error for the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Verry simple

```html
$to = 'someone@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'the message';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Hope helps you!

Source: http://w3webtools.com/send-email-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using build in crappy email() function, make a use of PHPMailer.
It is easy to use and does most of the hard work for You.

Features:

- Probably the world's most popular code for sending email from PHP!
- Used by many open-source projects: WordPress, Drupal, 1CRM, SugarCRM,
- Yii, Joomla! and many more Integrated SMTP support - send without a local mail server Send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and
- REPLY-TOs Multipart/alternative emails for mail clients that do not read HTML email Support for UTF-8 content and 8bit, base64, binary,
  and quoted-printable encodings SMTP
- authentication with LOGIN, PLAIN,    NTLM, CRAM-MD5 and Google's
  XOAUTH2 mechanisms over SSL and TLS    transports Error messages in
  47 languages!
- DKIM and S/MIME signing    support Compatible with PHP
    5.0 and later Much more!

All you have to do is to download and include this class to your project and then use it as in example:

A Simple Example

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

You'll find plenty more to play with in the examples folder at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.